# Dont display a alertview in a viewcontroller that it have been called from actionsheet

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, ios7, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I have a problem in iOS 7. In my project, I have a `UIViewController` that contains an actionsheet with same options, selected one and app loads new `UIViewController` from navitationbar (push).

I want display a alertview in this new `UIViewController` but I cant do it. I have same tests and I have concluded that the problem is the actionsheet becouse I delete it from app , alertview displays in screen.

Log Error (when I try display an alertview):

```
2013-10-24 08:40:02.078 app1[17406:a0b] Warning: Attempt to present <_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController: 0x17c19ea0>  on <_UIModalItemAppViewController: 0x1667a1c0> which is already presenting <_UIModalItemsPresentingViewController: 0x15395af0>
```

In iOS 6 works always.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code? You might be doing something weird. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would say it's a bug that this works on iOS6 which has been fixed in iOS7. Since both UIActionSheet and UIAlertView are modal view controllers displaying them simultaneously introduces airspace issues.

I think you've got no choice but to dismiss the UIActionSheet before displaying the UIAlertView which makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I select a actionsheet's option , it must dissmiss to open a new uiviewcontroller automatically.